# Is 马克又会汉语又会日语 an error in my Chinese book? Isn't 会汉语 incorrect?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

This is an example from my Chinese textbook:

[image]

I transcribe it below:

> [例如](http://dict.cn/%E4%BE%8B%E5%A6%82)：
>   <sup>Lìrú:</sup>
>   丁波的姐姐又高又漂亮
>   <sup>Dīngbō de jiějiě yòu gāo yòu piàoliang</sup>
>   马克又会[汉语](http://dict.cn/%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD)又会[日语](http://dict.cn/%E6%97%A5%E8%AF%AD)
>   <sup>Mǎkè yòu huì hànyǔ yòu huì rìyǔ</sup>

The second sentence takes me by surprise; it looks like an error to me.  I think 会汉语 (huì hànyǔ; "can Chinese") should be 会说汉语 (huì shuō hànyǔ; "can speak Chinese") or a variant like 会讲汉语.

**Question**: Is 马克又会汉语又会日语 an error in my Chinese book?

Comment: it is in any dictionary, and must have been discussed at this site before

Comment: Personally, I think both 会汉语 and 会日语 are not good expressions. I would always add a verb after 会，like 我会说汉语， 我会写英文， 我会玩游戏, etc. Sometimes, the verb can be omitted because it can be easily figured out without any ambiguity. But in 会汉语, you can put 说，读， 写... Most of time, you have to clarify after you say 我会汉语.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**会** here is a verb meaning *to know*.

Here are two sample sentences from A Chinese-English Dictionary:

> 他还会两出京戏。
>
> Tā hái huì liǎng chū Jīngxì.
>
> He knows a few airs of Beijing opera.

> 我会英语, 不会日语。
>
> Wǒ huì Yīngyǔ, bù huì Rìyǔ.
>
> I know English but not Japanese.

ABC dictionary defines it as *to understand* or *to grasp*

> 你会吗?
>
> Nǐ huì ma?
>
> Do you know how?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say it's wrong, but I would personally say : 马克既会汉语又会日语。as using two 又 sounds a bit silly... maybe just a feeling/habit thing tho. btw I am Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct. Note that [会](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/xs/4F1A.htm) doesn't mean `can` / `be able to`, but `know` / `understand` / `grasp` here.

> (8) 懂得 [know]。如:他会英文;他会做思想工作

On the other hand, `会说汉语` or `会讲汉语` limits the ability to *speaking* only.

Answer (score 0):

the sentence is correct but it usually appears in book or article.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. 会 means know, understand, have the ability to use it.

> He can speak Chinese. 他会说中文。
>
> She knows how to play guitar. 她会弹吉他。

Answer (score 0):

i from to china ,my english is not good,but i can chinese

马克又会汉语又会日语，这句话是正确的
马克又会汉语又会日语，it's correct。

在中国，可以这么省略这说
in china you can omit it;

会 说 汉语=会 汉语 ，
can=会(true/false)
speak=说(action)
chinese(language)=汉语(language)

speak just an action.

i english is so bad,i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

It's correct.
"会" is to show the ability of doing something, however usually put with a verb at the back to show "can do" something, such as "我`会说`汉语".

This is a special usage(without a verb at the back) almost only for languages. 
In languages the ability contains listening, speaking, reading and writing. 
So for saying "我会汉语" it means "I'm capable of listening, speaking, reading and writing Chinese", it's the overall skill rather than just speaking.